# why there are two process when i run python manage.py runserver

Tags: python, django, macos, process

```
wenzhixue      80384   0.4  1.1  2464788  22584 s001  S+   10:37AM   0:01.06 /usr/bin/python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
wenzhixue      80383   0.0  0.8  2451208  17300 s001  S+   10:37AM   0:00.62 python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Every time when I run python manage.py runserver, it brings up two process. why?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Maybe because of the autoreload option

Try to run it with [--noreload](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---noreload)

```
django-admin.py runserver --noreload
```