# Two processes created when run django in background

Tags: django

I found

`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 &`

will open 2 process when check by ps:

`ps -ef`

```
root     13884     1  0 18:01 ?        00:00:00 python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8088
root     13885 13884  0 18:01 ?        00:00:19 /usr/bin/python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8088
```

Why django open 2 processes? Is there any sequence if I want kill them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [why there are two process when i run python manage.py runserver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546176/why-there-are-two-process-when-i-run-python-manage-py-runserver)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The second process might be for auto-reloader.

Use the [--noreload](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---noreload) option to disable the use of the auto-reloader. By disabling this, any Python code changes will not take effect automatically if that particular Python module has already been loaded into memory, until server is restarted.

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --noreload
```