# Strange duplicate logs in django app while starting

Tags: python, django, multithreading

Basically I'm working on a website using django, and when I start the django app I can see that some lines are actually printed twice. Here is an example of logs: (in this case there is an error at the end, but when the app works correctly i don't see other duplicate logs, just at the startup)

```
>python manage.py runserver
test, this line should appear once!
test, this line should appear once!
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

couldn't import psycopg 'c' implementation: No module named 'psycopg_c'
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
```

Maybe this information can be useful, some months ago I had to use another thread in this same app to perform a long task without making the website unavailable in the meanwhile. I stopped working at this code for some time and now I don't remember exactly what I did but probably i messed up something. I know it's difficult to help me with not so many details, but I don't even know/remember where to look, I would appreciate advices for a better debug of what's going on
So I'm asking, why I see these duplcate logs? Maybe it's a multi threading problem? Thanks :)

**Update 1**

I was able to find the multi thread related code:

```
def my_view(request)
      t = threading.Thread(target=send_telegram_message,args=["text"], daemon=True)
      t.start()
      return ...
```

the send_telegram_message function, as the name suggests, is a function that sends an email to many users (this can take some time).

**Folder Structure**

```
   ecommerce_root
                 \__other_apps (there are 2 other apps)
                 \__static
                 \__website 
                           \__views,init,admin,models,signals,urls.py
                           \__migrations
                 \__ecommerce
                             \__settings,urls,asgi,wsgi,init.py
                 \__manage.py,requirements.txt
```

**Update 2**

If i run `python manage.py runserver --noreload` my app works without duplicate logs

Comment: look at manage.py ,wsgi.py,__init__.py.

Comment: @Pycm i wasn't able to see anything strange, so i posted the content of the files

Comment: can you post the full folder structure..

Comment: @Pycm Added at the end of the question and thanks for your time

Comment: The thing is people use<project>/urls.py , myapp/apps.py , <project>/wsgi.py files in different combinations. fi you can check them. or post them.

Comment: you can remove Folder Structure , wsgi.py, manage.py from the question if you want.

Answer (score 0):

1. 

If they are settings.py like files > That's how django development server work.

use `python manage.py runserver --noreload` to stop duplicate logs.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24365121/13861187

2. logging

Check settings.py for logging

```
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['applogfile', 'console'],
        'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO'),

        # prevent duplicate log in console
        'propagate': False,
       }
    }
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72583229/13861187

3. threading

**The thing is people use/urls.py , myapp/apps.py , /wsgi.py files in different combinations.**

So , ***How To Find Them***.

Method ,

1)
**Using Code Editor**

1. install sublime-text editor
2. open sublime-text editor
3. add project folder to sublime-text editor > by using manue or drag and drop
4. press ctrl+shift+f
5. fill `find` field with your text (`this line should appear once`)
6. click on the (...) button in where field
7. select your project folder
8. Click on `Find` button (don't click on Replace button)

This will find in any file in your project folder for text `this line should appear once` .

4)

**Remove/delete all **pycache** folders at project/app level**

(they are just cache, so you can delete them safely, they will be recreated automatically.)

Comment: I've done this check (using a different editor) and that text was found only in settings.py because there is 'print("test, this line should appear once!")

Comment: Then remove it. or comment it out.

Comment: I couldn't find it because I didn't see the content of settings.py .

Comment: If i remove that print obviously i don't see anymore the duplicate logs, but the actual problem is that some files are accessed twice. I deleted all pycache folders

Comment: Did happened to have change source files of Django ? is it possible?

Comment: how do you know? I mean which files?

Comment: If they are settings.py like files > That's how django development server work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24365121/13861187

Comment: One of these files it is settings.py, but this line (not in settings.py) is also repeated when running the server:
`Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Watching for file changes with StatReloader`